# How to update a table in loop

Tags: shell, database

I have a table name as Can

```
Internal_id not null VARCHAR2(10)
RCR            not null VARCHAR2(10)
IVC.            not null VARCHAR2(10)
```

Currently there no values for column RCR

The values stored in column Internal_Id are like

```
SER00001
SER00002 upto SER00093
```

I need to update RCR correspondingly to internal_id

Like for SER00001 it will be SERSRV00001

```
 SER00002 it will be SERSRV00002
```

and so on

I can do this like update Can where

```
RCR = lpad(Internal_id,3)||'SRV'||substr(Internal_id,4,6) where Internal_id = 'SER00001'
```

How to update in loop instead of writing so many update statements

Answer (score 0):

```
update MyTable set RCR = substr(Internal_id, 1, 3) || "SRV" || substr(Internal_id, 4);
```

You can do a `select` first to make sure it does the right thing:

```
select substr(Internal_id, 1, 3) || "SRV" || substr(Internal_id, 4) from MyTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse the right way to solve your query is using a SQL statement which @Kusalananda mentioned. But incase you specifically wanted to do it in loop(Oracle PL/SQL) then you can use this way as well:

```
 begin 
     for i in (select * from can) 
      loop  
        update can
        set RCR = substr(i.Internal_id, 1, 3) || "SRV" || substr(i.Internal_id, 4)
        where Internal_id = i.Internal_id;

        commit;
     end loop;
    end;
```